# Asymptotic growth of $f(n) = \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4^i} \right)^n $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I want to find the growth rate of $f(n)$ as $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} f(n)$

I can't find an other function that bounds this one in some form. Also the algebra manipulations involved here have confused me. I would appreciate a little help. Thanks.

Comment: [Geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am missing something,
$$(f(n))^{1/n} = \frac{1-4^{-n-1}}{1-1/4} - 1 = \frac{4-4^{-n}}{3} - 1 = \frac{1-4^{-n}}{3}. $$
Therefore, $$f(n) = \frac{(1-4^{-n})^n}{3^n},$$
the numerator converges to $1$ and the denominator converges to $+\infty$, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$.

Comment: numerator converges to $1$

Comment: @mercio ooops, thanks for the catch!